# Laravel toggle between pages with @if

Tags: php, laravel

I am fairly new to PHP and Laravel and I am trying to figure out how to toggle between "pages" so to speak.

For example. If there are no articles created I want to show the 'There are no articles created' message. Otherwise, I want to be redirected to a different page.

home.blade.php

```
@if($category->articles= null)
<div class="container">
   <p>There are no articles created</p>
</div>
@else
<div class="container">
   <p> go to the main page </p>
</div>
@endif
```

HomeController

```
 public function index(Category $category)
    {
        return view('home', [
            'category' => $category
        ]);
    }
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
      @if($category->articles= null)
use
      @if (count($category) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an anchor to be redirected by user action you have an error

```
// @if($category->articles == null)
// or
@if($category->articles->count())
<div class="container">
   <p>There are no articles created</p>
</div>
@else
<div class="container">
   <p> go to the main page </p>
</div>
@endif
```

Otherwise if you want to auto redirect to another page in the controller you will have to do something like this:

```
public function index(Category $category)
    {
        if($category->articles->count()) {
             return redirect(url('other/page'));
         }

        return view('home', [
            'category' => $category
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Albert many thanks for your help. I guess it was a bit trickier than that. However, your second option gave me an idea so here is the solution. `public function index()
    {

        $items = Category::all();

        if ($items->count() == null) {
            return view('home._home_no_category');
        } else {
            return view('home');
        }
    }` .

Comment: Glad to help! :)